# AngularJS - How to make a token inaccessible from console or malicious attacks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, xss, token

I'd like to store a token on the client but am worried about malicious attacks on the clients browser.

*What's the best way to store this variable **during the session?***

Here is my implication so far:

Create an isolated scope in the 'HeadersInterceptor' function so only that function can access it.

*What's the best way to store this variable **on client storage?***

Here is my implication so far:

Localstorage...

I do feel like I'm going in the right direction here, but I'm stumped on storing this variable for the client. Any insights would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want it available to the client side don't make it public.

Comment: I have to make it available to the client to use during each $http request to rest API server. What do you mean by public, like a public variable?

Comment: No by public I mean don't serve it up to the client.

Comment: Best way as I think is to encrypt it. That is the only way to really hide the data from malicious attacks. On server side you can use decryption algo to utilize on each request. But when storing on client side, do use encryption.

Comment: @RohitKumar but in that case I would just steal and use the encrypted token

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Anything that's accessible from your JS app is accessible from the developer console too, that's just the nature of client-side scripting.

Hiding it in a private variable or a service, as other answers suggest, are nothing more than obfuscation - it'll make it more of a nuisance to get, but it's there and available nonetheless.

Even if you find a method which makes it directly inaccessible from the developer console, per se, a malicious user will still be able to just modify the JS files themselves - it's a losing battle.

Comment: I'm not worried about someone getting their hands on the files. I'm worried about a user logged in with a valid token and an attacker getting that token from the client via XSS

Comment: @RobLaverty Why is that not mentioned in OP then?:) There's no *token-specific* protection against XSS, you should use general XSS-prevention patterns, regardless of what are you trying to protect. Once a malicious script is allowed to run, the token is not safe anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

My thoughts on this:

> What's the best way to store this variable during the session?

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> What's the best way to store this variable on client storage?

sessionStorage

But if you don't want it accessible at all, even from the console (sessionStorage and localStorage are accessible from the console), I would think you should forgo storing it in LS and simply hold a reference in memory. Keep the token wrapped in privately in a closure and access it via a service. Like so:

```
app.factory('tokenSvc', function(){
    var token;

    return {

        setToken: function(_token) {
            token = _token;
        },

        getToken: function() {
            return token;
        }
    };

});
```

Because Angular is a SPA framework, that `token` reference will persist as long as your application is active. So maybe you would set the token in your $http interceptor function, and then access it as need via `getToken`.

Comment: It would still be trivial to get the token by observing the http requests.

Comment: What I've done here is during app.run call an $http req with an intential error which is caught and gets the token. then get and set using this factory idea you have here. thank you ccnokes!